# A "contradiction" to Abel's theorem for series

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, summation

I proved that for every $0<a<1$, the series  $ \sum_{n=0}^\infty \left( \frac{x^{2n+1}}{2n+1} - \frac{x^{n+1}}{2n+2} \right) $ converges uniformly at $[-a,a]$ to $\frac{1}{2}\log (x+1)$.

Now, if we apply $x=1$ we get $\log 2$, but $\log 2 \ne \frac{1}{2} \log 2$.

Why isn't it a contradiction to Abel's theorem?

Comment: What is $a$? You mentioned it but in the series and in its value it doesn't appear. Did you mean $x$? Then if the interval remains $0<x<1$ it might not work simply because $x=1$ is outside that interval.

Comment: I've edited the question. Please notice the series is uniformly converges at $[-a,a]$ where $0<a<1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no contradiction, since in [Abel's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%27s_theorem), you consider a power series of the form:
$$
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nx^n
$$
Here, you don't have a power series, due to the powers $x^{2n+1} \neq x^{n+1}$ in the summand of your initial series.

Hoping to be clear.

Comment: Yes, thank you Olivier!

Comment: I'm confused. If the terms are rearranged in ascending order it certainly looks like a power series. Does this converge absolutely or conditionally?

Comment: @TimRaczkowski Please, can you elaborate (on the rearrangement), since each series is not absolutely convergent for $x=1$. Thanks.

Comment: I meant $\frac{1}{2}x -\frac{1}{4}x^2+\frac{1}{6}x^3+\dots$. Your comment about absolute convergence answers my question. Thanks.hey